Accessing docker container from another container in compose (but external)
I have simple docker-compose
version: '3'

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - applets_backend
      - dummy_backend
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_URL=http://applets_backend:8000
      - REACT_APP_DUMMY_API_URL=http://dummy_backend:8400
      - REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_TYPE=demo
    networks:
      - my-network

  applets_backend:
    build:
      context: ./applets_backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
    networks:
      - my-network

  dummy_backend:
    build:
      context: ./dummy_backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8484:8000"
    networks:
      - my-network

And my react app in container frontend need to make requests to other two services, but, when i open front on localhost:3000 i'm eventually getting problems that the address isn't correct, which is ok. But i don't understand how can i take the external address of my container to send requests
I tried to create nginx container
reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: "always"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8400:8400"
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    networks:
      - my-network`

and nginx.conf
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 8000;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://applets_backend:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8400;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://dummy_backend:8400;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

but this only works if i put localhost in the variables
environment:
- REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000
- REACT_APP_DUMMY_API_URL=http://localhost:8400
which is incorrect, i guess

Does the path-based reverse-proxy setup I describe in "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend help for this setup?

Weel, there was a reaaly good answer. But at this time - no, because i still have problems with my requests, because i got the problem with nginx, i guess.
My front from browser send request not to /applets_api/models/ask_question
but to http://localhost:3000/applets_api/models/ask_question
Cant print here my full config because of the message length

`events {}
http {
server {
listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /applets_api/ {
        proxy_pass http://applets_backend:8000;
    }
}

}`

End the docker-compose part with env variables for front
services:   frontend:     build:       context: ./frontend/       dockerfile: Dockerfile     ports:       - "3000:3000"     depends_on:       - applets_backend     environment:       - REACT_APP_API_URL=/applets_api       - REACT_APP_DUMMY_API_URL=/dummy_api       - REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=development       - REACT_APP_TYPE=demo

The ports are exposed to the host by
ports:
  - "8080:8000"

Your network is also user-defined bridge, so either you can access to the service by
http://applets_backend:8080 # Note 8080 instead of 8000

or
http://localhost:8000 # Note 8000 because it is exposed to the host

but never with
http://applets_backend:8000

which the first solution (using dns names with their internal port) is much better and standard. and you don't need to expose the internal services to host.

It doesn't work with http://applets_backend:8080 because our front is outside of the container and network, so from the browser's side it's unknown host http://applets_backend:8080
